# Kotlin - Class Inheritance; Overriding properties

Tags: kotlin, inheritance, subclass

So I started learning Kotlin today and got to Classes when I noticed something weird.
When I run this code:

```
fun main() {
    val dog_1 = Dog("Walrek", 7)
}

open class Animal(
    open val type: String,
    open val name: String,
    open val speed: Int,
) {
    init {
        println("(Ani init) New animal: $type called $name with $speed speed")
    }
}

class Dog(
    override val name: String,
    override val speed: Int,
): Animal("Dog", name, speed) {}
```

The init method will print out: `(Ani init) New animal: Dog called null with 0 speed`.

At first I thought I messed up somewhere and somehow I'm not passing the arguments properly into the `Animal` class, but then I added these two lines of code:

```
init {
    println("(Dog init) New animal: $type called $name with $speed speed")
}
```

into `Dog` class, and

```
println(dog_1.name)
```

in the `main` function, and got this as an output:

```
(Ani init) New animal: Dog called null with 0 speed
(Dog init) New animal: Dog called Walrek with 7 speed
Walrek
```

So now my question is, why weren't the parameters passed into the `Animal` class, and yet I can access them as usual after creating the `Dog` instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be getting a compiler warning. You should never use `open` properties or functions at construction time (in `init` blocks or property declarations), because it causes this kind of unwanted behavior. It's just about the only way you can get a NullPointerException in Kotlin without using `!!`.

The reason it happens is that the superclass's constructor (which includes `init` blocks and property declarations) is run before the subclass. Since you override the property `name` in the subclass, the backing field of the property `name` has not yet been initialized by the time `init` of the superclass is called, so the property returns the default Java field value of `null`. In the case of `speed`, the field type is a Java primitive `int` so its default value is 0.

Note that in your specific example, there was no need to override these properties because you are passing these values to the superconstructor anyway. You could remove the `open` keyword before the properties and declare your Dog like:

```
class Dog(
    name: String,
    speed: Int,
): Animal("Dog", name, speed) {}
```

Then it will behave properly.

Comment: Even if one initializes a value in the base class, for example `open val foo = 1`, and then overrides in the derived class `override val foo = 2` in this way, the behavior is still what is described in your answer(in my example output is 0 in the case derived class constructor is called), even though in Java it's OK to call overridden getters of final fields in base class' constructor and does not lead to unexpected results. Could you explain why is it different in Kotlin?

Comment: Simple answer to my question would be that in order to get expected result in that case(i.e. output - 2) the values should be known at a compile-time, which Kotlin doesn't seem to do without `const` modifier. Yet another disagreement with Java I guess.

Comment: Can you post a Gist or Pastebin of the Java behavior you’re describing? I’m not sure I understand. @getsadzeg

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Hrsi0qtc Here is the Java code -- it prints 2. In Kotlin the equivalent code(with `foo` being `open val`) prints 0 -- https://pastebin.com/whQ1Zcxd

This is straight from Coursera's "Kotlin for Java Developers", by the way.

Comment: @getsadzeg Ah, OK. The reason it's different is the way Kotlin creates backing variables for properties. When you override a property, the new property has no connection to any possible backing property of the super-property. In your Child class, when you assign the initial value of the overridden property, that means it gets its own backing field. But assignments of initial values of backing fields happens in construction order (which is why you are getting 0 and not 1 *or* 2. The Java equivalent of your example Kotlin Child class is:  https://pastebin.com/sEtBqzCa

Comment: You can't get Kotlin to assign its backing fields before the super constructor is called so you can't get the same behavior as your Java class in Kotlin. But in practice, it doesn't matter, since you should *never* call open functions or properties in an open constructor in Java or Kotlin, precisely because of these kinds of issues. Both the Kotlin and Java compilers issue warnings when you do this.